# Open a Path/Directory having space from Java Program

Tags: java, batch-file

I want to open a bat file from java program which is present at a path having some space like "C:\Users\yadavd2\eclipse-workspace\Test_Project\Hello World\ABC.bat"

Have already tried below approaches

```
String path1 = "C:\\Users\\yadavd2\\eclipse-workspace\\Test_Project\\Hello World\\ABC.bat";

URI u = new URI(path.trim().replaceAll("\\u0020","%20"));

 File file = new File(u.getPath());
             System.out.println("path1------>"+file.getPath());
             String[] command = {"cmd.exe", "/C", "Start", path1};
            Process p =  Runtime.getRuntime().exec(command);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works fine for me. I do not escape them at all.

```
System.out.println(new File("/tmp/test 1/").exists());
```

Ensure you are useing the correct file separator for your operating system.

```
System.getProperty("file.separator")
```

Comment: I am using Windows 10

Comment: Should not be a problem. Spaces should work fine by default. What is your System.getProperty("file.separator")?